# how to increment a like button in django with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

i have a post in a community and i have implemented the like button in django + ajax but i notice that when i do like a post it increments all the post's likes.how can i solve it ?
here is my template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
          <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round">
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ post.author.profile.avatar.url }}">
        <img src="{{ post.author.profile.avatar.url }}" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px"></a>
        <h4>
        <a href ='{% url 'profile' post.author.pk %}'>{{ post.author.profile.prenom|title }} {{ post.author.profile.nom|title }}</a>
        </h4>
        <span class="w3-opacity">{{ post.created|date:"d-m-Y H:i" }}</span>
         <br>
        <hr class="w3-clear">
        <p>
    {{ post.contenu }}</p>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          {{ post.comment_set.count }}  <a href='#'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> </a>
        </button>
    {% if request.user in post.liked.all %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
              <span class='like_count'>{{ post.liked.count }} </span><a name="{{ post.id }}" style="color: blue;" class="likin" id="co"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> j'aime</a>
    </button>
    {% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
           <span class='like_count'>{{ post.liked.count }} </span><a name="{{ post.id }}" style="color: black;" class="likin" id="co"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> j'aime</a>
    </button>
    {% endif %}
    {% if request.user == post.author %}
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <a href='{% url 'delete' post.id community.id %}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
        </button>
    {% endif %}
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    {% empty %}
    <span class='w3-opacity'>Aucun post dans cette communaute</span>
    <br>
    <br>
 {% endfor %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// AJAX CALL
$('.likin').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "{% url 'like_community' %}",
             data: {'content_id': $(this).attr('name'),'operation':'like_submit','csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(response) {
              selector = document.getElementsByName(response.content_id);
                    if(response.liked==true){
                      $(selector).css("color","blue");
                      $('.like_count').html(response.likes_count);
                    }
                    else if(response.liked==false){
                      $(selector).css("color","black");
                      $('.like_count').html(response.likes_count);
                    }


              }

        });

  })
</script>
```

this is my views.py with the part ajax like:

```
def like_community(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        if request.POST.get("operation") == "like_submit" and request.is_ajax():
            content_id=request.POST.get("content_id",None)
            content=get_object_or_404(Post,pk=content_id)
            if content.liked.filter(id=request.user.id): #already liked the content
                content.liked.remove(request.user) #remove user from likes
                liked=False
            else:
                content.liked.add(request.user)
                liked=True
            ctx={"likes_count":content.liked.count() ,"liked":liked,"content_id":content_id}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

i really need a help.i am new in ajax and i just find a tutorial online and i follow but the implementation of count_like button was not there.i will appreciate any help.Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have non-unique ID of "co" - Then you use the wrong method `document.getElementsByName` which returns a collection of NAMED elements but you pass it `response.content_id`

Also you use  `$('#response.content_id')` which will look for an element with  `id="response.content_id"

Change to

```
$('.likin').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault; // stop the link 
  $liked = $(this); // the link clicked
  $.ajax({
    success: function(response) {
       $liked.prev().html(response.likes_count); // the span before the "likin"
       $liked.css("color",response.liked==true ? "blue": "black");
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much it works amazingly you made my day.could you please advice me a good link to learn ajax because i am facing a problem also for reloading my page for showing new message user-to-user in my app i know i shoud use ajax with setinterval() in javascript  but i don't know how ? thanks again.

Comment: Never use setInterval with Ajax. Just use a setTimeout in the success

Comment: ok but in my app i want to reload the page every 1 minutes so that the user can see new messages if there is some and with settimeout it only reload the page one time.So can you advice me something.

Comment: No. You make a function that loads the data and in the success or done, you add the setTimeout to the same function with 60000 milliseconds so it will call again in one minute and so on

Comment: thanks i will try it.You are really amazing and nice person.

Comment: So something like `function loadPage() { $.ajax..... success: function() { setTimeout(loadPage,60000); }, ...}); }; $(function() { loadPage() });`